# Run skipped rspec tests and fail if they pass

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Let's say I have a bunch of tests:

`spec/code_spec.rb`:

```rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Code do
  xit { Code.evaluate("Twitter.search") }
  xit { Code.evaluate("Slack.send") }
  xit { Code.evaluate("Twitter.send") }
end
```

I get:

```
~/s/d/code> rspec spec/code_spec.rb

Randomized with seed 54828

Code
  example at ./spec/code_spec.rb:5 (PENDING: Temporarily skipped with xit)
  example at ./spec/code_spec.rb:6 (PENDING: Temporarily skipped with xit)
  example at ./spec/code_spec.rb:4 (PENDING: Temporarily skipped with xit)

Pending: (Failures listed here are expected and do not affect your suite's status)

  1) Code 
     # Temporarily skipped with xit
     # ./spec/code_spec.rb:5

  2) Code 
     # Temporarily skipped with xit
     # ./spec/code_spec.rb:6

  3) Code 
     # Temporarily skipped with xit
     # ./spec/code_spec.rb:4


Finished in 0.00251 seconds (files took 3.32 seconds to load)
3 examples, 0 failures, 3 pending

Randomized with seed 54828
```

What I would like is rspec to execute the tests and fail if they pass, ideally telling me I need to unskip them.

Is it possible?

Comment: fail if they pass?

Comment: That's what [`pending`](https://rspec.info/features/3-13/rspec-core/pending-and-skipped-examples/pending-examples/) is for: _"When a pending example passes  it will be marked as failed in order to communicate to you that it should no longer be marked as pending."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `pending: 'pending reason'` to test description

everything is described here https://www.joshmcarthur.com/til/2019/05/27/pending-block-examples-with-rspec.html

this test will be run by rspec, but will not fail whole test suite

```
it 'adds 1 + 1 and equals 3', pending: true do
  expect(1 + 1).to eq 3
end
```

but this test will fail, because no error was raised

```
it 'adds 1 + 1 and equals 2', pending: true do
  expect(1 + 1).to eq 2
end
```

Comment: `pending` also takes a reason why the example is pending which can provide helpful context to future coders (which includes future you). For example, `it 'does a thing', pending: "see issue #1234" do`

Comment: Niiiiiiiice, thanks, `pending` also works as a method inside the tests just like `skip`, e.g. `pending "search is not defined"`

Comment: and instead of doing `pending: true`, I can do `:pending`

Comment: Using the method variant works best for me as I can simply delete the whole line when I'm done (cleaner git diffs).